# What kind of cable do I have to use to administrate 3com SuperStack ® II Switch 3300?

Tags: networking, ethernet

Documantation for this switch says to use "Null modem cable". Do I have to use some kind of cable with one end "null modem" connector and the other end "Ethernet" connector? What is the name of it? Can I manage to do the same only with standard Ethernet cable?

Comment: Please provide us the documentation.  A `Null modem cable` is a serial cable, a serial cable, can't transfer at the sppeds, even close to that of a LAN port.

Comment: http://web.univ-pau.fr/~cpham/CNA/SWITCHS/dua1695-0baa05.pdf   and http://web.univ-pau.fr/~cpham/CNA/SWITCHS/16980ug5.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say that you can connect using the COM port (RS232) or through Ethernet to be able to manage the device through a number of different methods - web GUI, console etc.

https://www.mtmnet.com/PDF_FILES/3C16980_MgmtGuide.pdf - pg 33.

To be able to use Ethernet to access the device web GUI you need to **initially** configure the device to have an IP address - this (according to the documentation) can only be done via the serial console.

Once the device has been configured to have an IP and subnet you should be able to open the web GUI via the device's IP on your LAN.

**If your computer does not have a serial port (mainly new computers/laptops) then you will need to buy a USB-to-serial adapter.**

Comment: How can I connect through Ethernet if while my laptop connected to the switch, it cannot set up/ negotiate connection parameters? I cannot ping  the switch. I use Windows 7.

Comment: Your documentation clearly states that you must configure the device using the console to give the device an IP. It looks like you may have no other option but to buy a USB-to-Serial adapter for your computer and the cable (RS232/Null modem) to initially configure the device. You have an enterprise class device - I think they would hope you already had the tools available.

Comment: If the device is connected to a DHCP server on your network (I.e. DHCP -> Your Switch -> Your PC) - the device may be able to obtain an IP automatically. The docs don't say what the default method is for the switch to get an IP (auto/manual). You might then be able to have a look on your DHCP server what IP has been given to the device... you could then try that IP in your browser?

Comment: Can I use serial-to-Ethernet cable? If yes, I suppose I have to use Telnet to configure device. Right? http://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Otj.jpg

Comment: Again, your docs clearly state the device must have an IP before you can manage it via the web GUI. A serial-to-Ethernet is doing exactly what your on-board Ethernet NIC is doing... not working.

Comment: I mean, Serial connector goes to the switch, Ethernet connector goes to pc. Not the other way. This won't work (for example, for Telnet connection)?

Comment: @RCola - Just use a USB-To-Serial cable.  They are cheap, dirt cheap, and its the simplest way for non-technical people to configure this device.

Comment: As Ramhound says. Info: The USB-to-Serial is not simply a "cable" - it has conversion hardware inside that converts USB signals to RS232 signals.

Comment: Thanks, I got it! But can you answer why this scheme would/wouldn't work `Serial connector goes to the switch, Ethernet connector goes to pc.` ?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by this. The "serial" port on the switch is purely for configuring and monitoring the device.

Comment: I mean, can I use instead of USB-to-Serial the other cable/adapter Ethernet-to-Serial purely for administration tasks `configuring and monitoring the device`?

Comment: Not unless your switch has an RJ45 "console" port: http://1000servers.com/media/catalog/product/cache/5/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/e/rear_cisco_catalyst_ws-3750g-48ts_serverhome.jpg - once you've configured your device you can configure and monitor it using it's IP on your network... why would you want to do it any other way?

Comment: Assuming I don't have USB-to-Serial cable and I have only Ethernet-to-Serial cable. Again, Ethernet jack goes to laptop, Serial connects to switch console port.....

Comment: It won't work that way. The cable you have found is specifically for managed switches that have RJ45 "console" ports. This is technically still serial-to-serial. To do true "ethernet-to-serial" you need to convert ethernet signals to serial signals (http://store.homeseer.com/store/Assets/ProductImages/IP2SL-500-1.jpg) - It is not simply a "cable".

Answer (score 0):

A "Null modem cable" is the standard [RS232 cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem) that can be connected to the COM port. 
[image]

It is also possible to configure switch using a standard Ethernet cable. see the page 34 of this [user guide](https://www.mtmnet.com/PDF_FILES/3C16980_MgmtGuide.pdf)

Comment: I don't have COM port on my laptop... I have port for VGA cable which looks similar but I doubt it is going to work. Is it?

Comment: @RCola - If you don't have a COM port on your laptop then you cannot use a `Null modem cable`.  As for what cable to use, the user guide, fully describes what you should use.

Comment: @RCola : No you cant connect switch to the VGA port on your laptop.But it is important that you have to configure your switch using a RS232 cable. you have to provide IP for switch and then only you will be able to connect and configure through web interface.